# play and pause videos in React-Native FlatList or Play video only one Video visible

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Hi i am doing video Gallery app like TikTok using React-Native with FlatList , While i am doing the app i got the error with videos play and pause options. When i open the app all videos are playing at a time in the background but i want to play the only one video which is visible one the screen or in the view point. 
So once check the below code and give me any better suggestions ..

```
import SegmentedControlTab from 'react-native-segmented-control-tab';
import Video from 'react-native-video';
import VideoPlayer from 'react-native-video-controls';

import MediaControls, { PLAYER_STATES } from 'react-native-media-controls';

import axios from 'axios';

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  _isMounted = false;
  constructor(Props) {
    super(Props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoading: false,

      playing: false,
      currentTime: 10,
      duration: 0,
      isFullScreen: false,
      isLoading: true,
      paused: true,
      playerState: PLAYER_STATES.PLAYING,
      screenType: 'content',

    };

    this.viewabilityConfig = {
      waitForInteraction: true,
      viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 95
    }


  }
  onViewableItemsChanged = ({ viewableItems, changed }) => {
    console.log("Visible items are", viewableItems);
    console.log("Changed in this iteration", changed);
  }




 render() {
    const { duration, paused, overlay } = this.state

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>        

         <FlatList style={styles.list}
                data={this.state.following_Posts}
                // keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                keyExtractor={(data_Posts, index) => {
                  return data_Posts.id.toString();
                }}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={() => { return (<View style={styles.separator} />) }}

               // viewabilityConfig={{ viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 95 }}
              viewabilityConfig={this.viewabilityConfig}

              onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged}
              viewabilityConfig={{
                itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 95
              }}

                refreshing={this.state.isLoading}
                onRefresh={this.getFollowingPosts}
                renderItem={(posts, id) => {
                  const items = posts.item;
                  return (
                    <View style={styles.card}>                    

                      <View style={styles.cardContent}>
                        {items.file_Name.toString().endsWith("mp4") ?
                          <View>
                            <Video
                              onEnd={this.onEnd}
                              onLoad={this.onLoad}
                              onLoadStart={this.onLoadStart}
                              onProgress={this.onProgress}
                              paused={this.state.paused}
                              ref={videoPlayer => (this.videoPlayer = videoPlayer)}
                              onFullScreen={this.state.isFullScreen}
                              resizeMode="cover"
                              volume={10}
                              source={{ uri: "http://192.168.1.3:3200/" + items.file_Name }}
                              style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0, }}

                            />
                            <MediaControls
                              duration={this.state.duration}
                              isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
                              mainColor="#333"
                              onFullScreen={this.onFullScreen}
                              onPaused={this.onPaused}
                              onReplay={this.onReplay}
                              onSeek={this.onSeek}
                              onSeeking={this.onSeeking}
                              playerState={this.state.playerState}
                              progress={this.state.currentTime}
                              toolbar={this.renderToolbar()}
                            />
                          </View>
                       </View>
      />
   </View>
  )
 }
```

If anyone find anything wrong in code code please tells me , If anyone better solution please help me with the code ...
Thank you to all programmers ...

Comment: Hi! Have you done this ? I am also working on this type functionality using FlatList. Let me know if you done this.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one, `const { duration, paused, overlay } = this.state` is declared but you're still accessing state in JSX with `this.state`.

Your `onViewableItemsChanged` function doesn't mutate state or do anything besides log stuff out to the console.

And you either left out or didn't finish writing the onLoad, onEnd, onProgress, etc. functions. So, it's kind of impossible to know exactly what's going on. If you just omitted those functions in order to post this question, are you updating the `paused` state in any of those functions?

Comment: thank you for your reply i don't have much knowledge on React-native, So i am unable to understand what you are saying , i am a new learner so if you have full code suggestion please tell me .

Comment: I don't have time to start up a project and help you with it. But I would suggest watching some videos or reading tutorials on how to use FlatList and SectionList. Read the React Native docs too. For example: `this.onEnd` is supposed to call an `onEnd` method in your component. The weird part is that `this.state.paused` is false, so the videos should not be playing. Try the react-native-video GitHub issues thread. See if you can find anything. Good luck.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion , playing the videos is not m issue all videos are playing at a time is the main issue so i am trying to implement  play the video on view . Thank you for your suggestions .

Answer (score -1):

```
import { Viewport } from '@skele/components'
```

Use this component, it resolved for me, this component helps you track one video at a time and plays only the video that is visible on screen

even, am a newbie in react native, hence this is the easiest solution one could get

Comment: can you please provide an example . it will help